# Antiderivative definition

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives, soft-question

Recently, I was trying to derive the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ by taking

$$\lim_{p\to-1}\;\;\int{x^p}$$

but quickly realized that it would not work as it gives

$$\frac{x^0}{0}$$

however, if I instead took

$$\lim_{p\to-1}\;\;\int_a^x{x^p}$$

This gives

$$\lim_{p\to-1}\;\;\frac{x^{p+1}-a^{p+1}}{p+1}$$

Which evaluated with L'Hopital's rule returned

$$\ln(x)-\ln(a)$$

where $\ln(a)$ is just some constant and returns the expected result.

This leads me to ask, is the antiderivative **defined** as a definite integral with variable upper bound, or is there something else I'm not understanding here? I looked at the fundamental theorem of calculus, for hints and this seems to be the case, but there was nothing definitive that said this was true.

Comment: Limits are always written on the left hand side, and the antiderivative of $f(x)$, say $F(x)$, is a function so that $\frac{d}{dx}F(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: Thank you I fixed that

Comment: The problem is due to the fact that if an anti-derivative exists then it is not unique. Choosing the anti-derivative $\dfrac{x^{p+1}-1}{p+1}$ works fine. Also note that limit of an integral is not necessarily equal to the integral of limit, but in most interesting and useful cases they are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close to a good answer.

### The logarithm function

Formally, the logarithm function is defined as a function that is a solution to the logarithmic differential equation

$$ \begin{cases}F'(x) = \frac{1}{x}, \text{ for all } x>0 \\ F(1) = 0 \end{cases} $$

rather than as an antiderivative of the derivative of $\frac{1}{x}$.

Such function satisfies the three properties of a logarithmic operation which can be proved through properties of the differential equation. The logarithm is an antiderivative only in the sense that it is the solution to the differential equation that is being integrated.

To illustrate, consider this property of the logarithm.

i) $F(ab) = F(a) +F(b)$ (Fitzpatrick, Theorem 5.1.i)

Define a function $g:(0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ as $g(x) = F(ax) - F(a) - F(x)$. It follows that

$$ g'(x) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left( F(ax) - F(a) - F(x) \right) = \frac{a}{ax} - 0 - \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x} = 0$$

This satisfies the criteria for the identity criterion, so we can then conclude $F(ax) = F(a) + F(x)$.

### Indefinite Integration

Indefinite integration is a special case of the first part of the First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (integrating derivatives).

The theorem states that for a function $F:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ that is continuous over $[a,b]$ (a closed interval) that has a continuous and bounded derivative over the open interval $(a,b)$, the function $F$ satisfies
$$\int_a^b F'(x) \mathrm{d}x = F(b) - F(a) $$

We'd like to pick values of $a$ and $b$ such that
$$ \int_a^b F'(x) \mathrm{d}x = F(t) $$
Which is obtained by selecting $a = t$ and $b$ such that $F(b) = 0$. (Note that $b = 1$ satisfies $ln(1) = 0$, the initial condition of the logarithm differential equation.)

This gives
$$ \int_a^t F'(x) \mathrm{d}x = F(t) $$
Which can then be differentiated pursuant to the Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (differentiating integrals) at $t = x$ to obtain $F'(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a version of the fundamental theorem of calculus. The rate of change of the definite integral with respect to the upper limit is the integrand.

But your reasoning here is suspiciously circular since to use L'Hopital you must already know a lot about the natural logarithm - probably something equivalent to what you are trying to prove.

Comment: no, all it meant is that some $\frac{d}{dp}x^p$ is $\ln(x)x^p$ it is evaluated by rewriting $e^{p\ln(x)}$ and using the definition of the derivative of an exponential and the chain rule

Comment: But I could be totally wrong. I don't have any formal teaching in rigorous mathematics I only learned what I needed to for engineering and even then the lessons were more about application than theory and understanding. I am trying to now get a better understanding of the fundamental concepts and rigorous definitions as I really love the subject.

Comment: Good for you for trying to find that understanding. I don't think this question is a good place to look for it. To get at the natural log rigorously you define it either as the integral from $1$ to $x$ of $1/x$ or as the function that inverts exponentiation, and prove all the other properties from whichever starting point you prefer. There are places to look this stuff up - web search might find them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Ethan I think you meant "the integral from $1$ to $x$ of $\frac{1}{t}dt$".

Comment: @user496634 Yes, but it's too late to edit my comment.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{1}{x}dx=\ln|x|+C$$
if this is true, then:
$$\frac{1}{x}=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\ln|x|\right]$$
let $$y=\ln(x)$$
then
$$e^y=x$$
$$e^y\frac{dy}{dx}=1$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{e^y}=\frac{1}{x}$$